# Listing all transactions of an account from a specific period of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. Account

```
account_id2  | account_name`
   11111        ABC
   55555        HEY
   99999        XYZ
```

2. Journal

```
jid | date       |  dbt_id  | description | total_value |  cr_id  |
 1    13/02/2020    11111        XXXXX         5000        55555
 2    15/02/2020    99999        YYYYY         100         11111
```

I need to list all transactions from a certain period of time of a certain account.
For example, for the date 13/02/2020 - 15/02/2020 for account 11111,

The query should produce a result like below:

```
jid |    date    |  cr_name   |   debit   | description |   db_name   |  credit  |
 1    13/02/2020      HEY          5000        XXXXX                 
 2    15/02/2020                               YYYYY          XYZ         100
```

Here are what I have tried

```
-- Listing all CREDIT transactions with the name of the Debit account
SELECT j.jid, j.date, a.account_name as db_name, FORMAT(j.total_value,0) AS credit, j.description
FROM journal AS j INNER JOIN account AS a
ON j.dbt_id = a.account_id2
WHERE j.cr_id = 11111; 

-- Listing all DEBIT transactions with the name of the Credit account
SELECT j.jid, j.date, a.account_name as cr_name, FORMAT(j.total_value,0) AS debit, j.description
FROM journal AS j INNER JOIN account AS a
ON j.cr_id = a.account_id2
WHERE j.dbt_id = 11111;


-- So in an effort to join them
SELECT 
   j.jid, j.date, a.account_name AS cr_name, FORMAT(j.total_value,0) AS debit, j.description, 
   b.account_name AS dbt_name, FORMAT(k.total_value, 0) AS credit, k.description
FROM journal AS j
  INNER JOIN journal AS k
        ON k.dbt_id = j.dbt_id
  INNER JOIN account AS a
        ON j.cr_id = a.account_id2
  INNER JOIN account AS b
        ON k.dbt_id = b.account_id2
WHERE j.dbt_id = 11111 OR k.dbt_id = 11111;
```

But it produces every single combinations of entries that satisfies the WHERE condition

Please do help. I have searched various posts and tutorials and yet have not found similar case.

Comment: You need 'union all' Google will help you find what to do from there

Comment: I don't like the journal design , are you stuck with it?

Comment: @LJ01 I have tried with union all, but they dont remove the opposing transaction... would you mind providing more guidance?

Comment: @P.Salmon May I ask what do you have in mind? I have come across others like double rows but I thought there would be more extra rows and repeated columns if I do that.

Comment: My comment above is now irrelevant - superseded by answer after I reviewed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you are looking for the below.

```
select j.jid, , j.date, 
      iif(j.dbt_id=11111,null,d.account_name)    as dr_name,
      iif(j.dbt_id=11111,null,total)             as debit, 
      description, 
      iif(j.crd_id=11111,null,c.account_name)    as cr_name,
      iif(j.crd_id=11111, null,total)            as credit
from journals j join accounts d on a.account_id2 = j.dbt_id
                join accounts c on c.account_id2 = j.crd_id
where j.dbt_id = 11111 or j.crd_id = 11111
```

Comment: Oh wow! LJ01, May I ask if it's a precaution for something to use **iif** instead of **if**?
 And of course, Thank you so very much @LJ01!! This is what I am trying to achieve. Truly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Iif is a short hand replacement for'case when'. If is to say check something, and if true run this query, otherwise run that query, it doesn't modify the output on a row by row basis

Comment: Hmm, is that like mysql jargon or is it supposed to be registered that way in mysql? Since I couldnt run it if it is 'iif'. Surprisingly, when I run it with IF, it actually worked?

Comment: Uh. I use msSQL so its quite possible that my prior comment is completely irrelevant... it applies for msSQL, sorry I didn't even check your tags for what DB engine you use

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking two `LEFT JOIN`s.  I find the ordering of your columns a little hard to follow, but this is the basic idea:

```
SELECT j.jid, j.date, ac.account_name as cr_name, 
       (case when ac.account_name is not null then j.total_value end) AS credit,
       j.description,
       (case when ad.account_name is not null then j.total_value end) ad.account_name ad db_name,
       j.total_value AS credit
FROM journal j LEFT JOIN
     account ad
     ON j.dbt_id = ad.account_id2 LEFT JOIN
     account ac
     ON j.cr_id = ac.account_id2
WHERE 11111 IN (j.dbt_id, j.cr_id);
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff! Thank you very much for the reply! This is very close to the result I would like to have.
This query produces a result of:

jid |    date     |  cr_name   |   debit   | description |   db_name   |   credit  |
1    13/02/2020    HEY           5000        XXXXX          ABC            5000
2    15/02/2020    ABC            100         YYYYY          XYZ             100

Hmm... comment does not show it well... but the result is **exactly the same as per the example journal**.
Is there a way to **remove the searched criteria ( "ABC")** from appearing from the output?

Comment: @albert . . . I think a `union all` approach would do that.  That at least explains why I find the output format hard to follow.